# using SK S7G2 board on any existing project, Every time I encounter error

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessors

I have been assigned to either choose an existing project or make new project using SK S7G2 board as a homework with limited time and I haven't been taught about these board anything ("I know, great teachers").

I found many project online and when I try to debug them, the program (e2 studio version 7.5 ...) show me some error massages. I have been trying to find solution online and from there website (renesasrulz.com) but I couldn't find something useful.

Can anyone help me? please

Projects that I tested:

- S7_SK_guix_audio_player
- S7_SK_hal_uart_1_1_0
- S7_SK_Weatherpanel
- S7G2_DK_ADC_DMAC_CONTINUOUS
- S7G2_SK_TRI_WAVE_PWM1
- S7G2_DK_ADC_DMAC_CONTINUOUS

Comment: Please include the error messages you are seeing when you try to debug the project.

Comment: YES, tell us the error messages! Otherwise how can we help you? Anyway, do you know that you must open a project, compile it, transfer it to the board, then finally debug it? If any step fails, the other can not succeed.